# I need to edit the bash script to select a letter to do separate commands

Tags: bash

I am not sure what step is next in the process to get the commands to do what I want. I want to select a letter to do a command. Right now it lets you use any letter.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please select l to list files of a directory, b to backup a file or directory, u to edit a user's password, and x to exit the script"

read $answer

if [ $answer="l" ]; then

printf "Please select folder:\n"
select d in */; do test -n "$d" && break; echo ">>> Invalid Selection"; done
cd "$d" && pwd

ls

fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a case statement

```
case expression in
    pattern1 )
        statements ;;
    pattern2 )
        statements ;;
    ...
esac
```

e.g:

```
case $arg in
    l)
        printf "Please select folder:\n"
        select d in */; do test -n "$d" && break; echo ">>> Invalid Selection"; done
        cd "$d" && pwd
        ls
        ;;
    cmd1)
        echo "Some other cmds line 1"
        echo "Some other cmds line 2"
        ;;
    -q) exit;;
    *) echo "I'm the fall thru default";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `select` builtin for this, which will let you use numbers for each option instead of letters, but will take care of reading and validating input:

```
select cmd in \
  "List files of a directory" \
  "Backup a file or directory" \
  "Edit a user's password" \
  "Exit";
do
  case $cmd in
  1) do_list_files ;;
  2) do_backup_files ;;
  3) do_edit_password ;;
  4) exit 0 ;;
  esac
done
```

You can change the prompt by setting the `PS3` variable (e.g. `PS3="Your choice? "`)